# How I Create a Job if my shared host don't show me SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a problem for create a SQL job, in my local machine I have just .\SQLExpress, but my site stay in a Shared Host, and in this SQL instance I don't see the SQL Agent for create a SQL Job.

Who I do creating a job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jobs can actually be scripted in. 
Here's an article that might be useful http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2161/sql-server-agent-job-management-scripts/

I believe another solution could be to reverse engineer an existing job created through Management Studio by using the IDE to script it out for you. I know you only have SQL Express, so that might not be feasible :-)

Comment: Incredible but when I execute the command "EXEC dbo.sp_add_job @job_name = N'Job1'GO " I get the message sp_add_Job doesn't exist...

Comment: I talk with my host and discovery my host sale this service.... more 24€ per year. I need outer solution.

Comment: Ok, it's hard to recommend an alternative solution without knowing the requirements. Does your job have to be at the database level?

Answer (score -2):

SQL Express does not include the SQL Agent. Sorry.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked, which is "how do I create a SQL Server job on a shared host site that doesn't give me access to SQL Agent?". The poster didn't say that the hosted site only had SQL Express; the question says his *local machine* only has SQL Express.